# Detect headphones on a laptop in Windows

Tags: c#, .net, windows, desktop-application, naudio

I am currently working on a Windows Desktop application which should get notified on any changes in connected audio devices.

I am currently using the Core Audio Interface API through the [NAudio](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NAudio/) package in the following manner:

```
NAudio.CoreAudioApi.MMDeviceEnumerator enumerator;   

public void PopulateAudioDevices()
{
    enumerator = new NAudio.CoreAudioApi.MMDeviceEnumerator();

    var endpoints = enumerator.EnumerateAudioEndPoints(
        DataFlow.Render,
        DeviceState.Unplugged | DeviceState.Active);
}

protected override void OnStart()
{
    PopulateAudioDevices();

    if (enumerator != null)
    {
        enumerator.RegisterEndpointNotificationCallback(this);
    }
}

public void OnDeviceStateChanged(string deviceId, DeviceState newState)
{
    Console.Writeline($"{deviceName} : Device State {newState}");
}
```

This seems to work fine for most USB devices however it seems that there are cases in which connecting a device through the external headphone jack on a laptop does not result in the OnDeviceStateChanged callback being triggering. One differentiating factor that I noticed is that in these cases there were no visible changes in the Windows 'Device Manager' screen when an external audio device was plugged in. I have however noticed that the Windows Volume setting does change whenever an audio device was plugged in. This led me to believe that the OS is somehow registering a difference in connected devices.

Is there any way to detect such cases?

Comment: If you don't receive any event then you may try to call PopulateAudioDevices in a timer in order to detect the headphones.

Comment: there is no guarantee that windows will be told at all when headphones are plugged into a soundcard (particularly if it is an external soundcard). You are reliant on the soundcard driver providing this information, who will decide whether to present this to the OS as a separate "device" or not.